# php mysqli fetch object

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Can anyone find any mistakes in my PHP code?

```
<?php
$keyword=$_GET['keyboards'];
$sql = "SELECT *FROM MyGuests WHERE lastname LIKE '$keyword'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$sss=mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($sss)
{
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_object($result)){       
        **echo "id: " . $row['lastname'].  "<br>";**            
    }
}
?>
```

The problem line is here:

```
echo "id: " . $row['lastname'].  "<br>";
```

Comment: you fetched object, shouldn't you call property: `$row->lastname` ?

Comment: What is "the problem" ... an error? empty? failing to get that far? What?

Comment: Your checking of `$sss` is completely redundant. If there are zero rows, the `while` loop will not execute anyway

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
while ($row =$result->fetch_object()) {
        echo $reg->lastname;
        }
```

or

```
while ($row =$result->fetch_object()) {
        echo $reg['lastname'];
        }
```

Comment: I like your attempt to use somebody else knowledge. But at least check you variable names.